# Based on status_id want to populate an assigned string on an index page but it will only populate the status_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using a drop down menu to determine the status of a Show is/was: "Watched," "Watching," or "To-Watch"  I am trying to display the status on the shows page and it will only populate the status_id. This feels pretty basic, but I've tried many iterations and even did a nested attribute in my controller. The only way I can populate it is Status.last.watched, etc. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
***schema.rb***
create_table "statuses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "watched"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "show_id"
    t.index ["show_id"], name: "index_statuses_on_show_id"

  create_table "shows", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "show_title"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "note_id"
    t.integer "status_id"
  end
```

```
***params in shows_controller.rb***
  def show_params
    params.require(:show).permit(:show_title, :status_id, status_attributes: [:watched])
  end
```

```
***index.html.erb***
   <% @shows.each do |s| %>
   <h4><li><%= link_to s.show_title, show_path(s.id) %></h4>
    <p><%= s.status_id %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you kind of failed at the database design stage. If you have shows and users and want to keep track of which users have watched what you want to setup a join table and put the status there.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_shows
  has_many :shows, through: :user_shows
end

# rails g model UserShow user:belongs_to show:belongs_to status:integer
# adding a unique compound index on user_id and show_id is a good idea
# if you are using PG you can use a native Enum column type instead of an integer
class UserShow < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: { watching: 0, watched: 1, to_watch: 2 }
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :show
  validates_uniqueness_of :show, scope: :user_id
end

class Show < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_shows
  has_many :shows, through: :user_shows
end
```

This creates a many to many association between Users and Shows. In your code a show can only be associated with a single status. That means you would have to duplicate everything on the shows table for every user.

I have no idea what you're trying to do with `t.string "watched"`. A boolean would be slight improvement. But an [ActiveRecord::Enum](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) would let you keep track of the status without multiple boolean columns.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding. This is super helpful. Had the boolean initially and then went down this awful string rabbit hole.

Comment: I hope this clears things up. To check if a user has watched a show you need to query the user_shows table `show.user_shows.find_by_user_id(user.id).status`. You don't need/want to use nested attributes for the dropdown - you just want a form that creates/updates rows on the user_shows table.

Answer (score -1):

To get the status string to show in your view you want to change `<%= s.status_id %>` to `<%= s.status.watched %>`.

That being said, the way you have this setup, I would make another column in the `shows` table, call it `status`, and have it be of type string. Then you can set the status as one of three you listed. You could then get rid of the `status_id` column in `shows` and the whole `statuses` table.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, <%= s.status.watched %> is flipping a NoMethodError. When I drop in the console, the only way to access the string is to assign Status.last as q1, for example, and then call q1.watched. Thanks for the tip on the new column. Considered that, but wanted to see if this would work first.